# Lubuntu, panel items are not arranged in proper way

Tags: lubuntu, lxde, lxpanel

My Lubuntu panel contains some running applets, but they are not arranged in order, and there is empty space between them. This particularly annoys me when using minimized windows.

Take a look at the image; that will explain what I'm trying to say:

[image]

I don't have it any more exactly like this, but I can't see the minimized windows on upper panel. I have created another upper panel and customized it as I need but my minimized windows are not displaying there either.

How can I sort my Panel?

Comment: Are you using spacers? what are the contents of your panel applets in panel settings?

Comment: i am not using any spacers between them . i am using application indicator , Weather Indicator ,Guake ,system monitor with sound applet .

Comment: ok that was selected and i have seen the changes too , but will it be saved or set back to previous case after restart .thank you . mention it as one answer .

Comment: It will be that way permanently. Any changes to that Panel Prefernces dialog should take immediate and permanent effect.

Comment: Do you have other desktop environments installed, besides Lubuntu/LXDE? I think this may be a bug triggered by some other desktop environment. Something similar has been happening on multiple Lubuntu machines of mine, but only when I have other DE's installed as well.

Comment: @Eliah Kagan , Yes i have . I am with Ubuntu-unity , Gnome all desktops , Lubuntu,Xubuntu and other desktops too.

Comment: @mattdavis Check out my answer to you question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok after many trails on this issue . i did some progress . The first thing is delete the panel  if it sounds bad , restart the panel .i did the process with only one panel.

```
ps -C lxpanel
```

Thats going to display the PID of `lxpanel`.
Then we have to kill the lxpanel process .

```
kill <pid of the lxpanel>
```

then again in the terminal type as

```
lxpanel
```

Thats will do the restart of `lxpanel` with proper arrangement of the all panel elements.I need help about how to make it as script , because i am failing while getting the process ID and one more thing is to run the script all time , then only we can achieve this .

and one more thing about how to get minimized applets on the panel means we have to add a panel item " Task bar(window list) " panel item.then minimized windows will be in panel.

Comment: You can also just use `lxpanelctl restart` though it should be easy to script it. That might make it easier to script it, at any rate. Have fun.

Answer (score 4):

If that is the total contents of your panel then you need to add a "Task Bar(Window List)" from your Panel Preferences. This is the applet that will show your current windows. When you set it to the panel, check the box under the "Stretch" collumn. This will push everything to either side of it to the edge of your screen.

Comment: hey the changes are reverting back to normal after a restart . the solution you have given is good for after restart as a do task . thank you .

Comment: So the addition of the stretched Task Bar to your panel is a permanent solution to your problem?

Comment: no man , the issue back again :(

Comment: So is the Task Bar (Windows List) gone after a restart? If so then it is not saving it's configuration.

Comment: You may try 'sudo apt-get install --reinstall lxpanel' in terminal. Any changes to the Lxpanel should take permanent effect. If not, it would seem that it's corrupted somehow.

Comment: ok i will try and report you back , thank you :)

Comment: hey thats not working . still same . i think its a bug .

Comment: My other suggestion then would be to recreate the panel. Right click your current panel and select "Create New Panel". Then edit the new panel how you want it to be and see if that sticks. If so you can then just delete the bad panel.

Comment: You could also check in ~/.config/lxpanel/Lubuntu/panels/. This directory keeps your lxpanel config files. There should be one file per panel in use. This file can be opened in leafpad and you can see what plugins it is using.

Comment: i havent found that .

Answer (score 1):

This video I did will help you: http://youtu.be/4XQogD4NkJw

And don't forget to add as the @mattdavis said the "Task Bar(Window List)" from the Panel Preferences > Panel Applets (tab) > Add (button).

To download it, use the following commands on the terminal:

1. Install `youtube-dl` (command line YouTube video downloader):

   ```
   sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
   ```
2. Run it on your terminal:

   ```
   youtube-dl http://youtu.be/4XQogD4NkJw
   ```

Comment: i am appreciating your help but my Internet very slow (20-25 KBPS) i cant watch it with that and its going to take huge time .

Comment: add `FlashGot` to `Firefox` and use `FlasGot Media` (ctrl-F7) to download and see it offline

Comment: @GrSr The video has only 2MB. I edited the answer showing how to download it using the terminal.

Comment: @GrSr I hope you get the video now using youtube-dl it's very light tool.

Comment: Your answer is good up to adjust few applets like sound and clock but its not provided any option for adjusting those guake terminal ,weather indicator , sys monitor applet . Thank you but i have tried something and that worked  for me ..

Answer (score 1):

This bug has been happening to me too. Please subscribe to the bug report on https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxpanel/+bug/1004224.

Answer (score 0):

On my LXLE 14.04: Right click on Task bar (Window list) > 'panel settings' (confusingly called "Panel preferences" in the pop-up) > check on tab 'Panel Applets' which applets have the Stretch parameter activated (or not).